# Java RMI in non-local environment

Tags: java, rmi

Im losing my mind, is there any clear documentation how to run java RMI between host and client remotly? i find in different forums, various puzzle pieces, but never, a from a to z guide, which scurity guidelines have to be followed etc, so that a RMI works. Well, if I run the server and client locally, it works.

Now, my low-level problem is that even if I set the external server address everywhere (?), in the error message it says that "localhost" has refused the connection.... Do you have any ideas?

Client:

```
        try {
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","42.155.241.914");
        String name = "RemoteBookService";
        String serverIP = "42.155.241.914"; // or localhost if client and server on same machine.
        int serverPort = 1099;
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverIP, serverPort);

        IRemoteService rs = (IRemoteService) registry.lookup(name);
```

Error:

> ```
> java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost;
> nested exception is: 
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
> ```

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, AlreadyBoundException {
            
    try {
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","42.155.241.914");
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        String name="//42.155.241.914/RemoteBookService";
        RemoteService rs = new RemoteService();
        Naming.bind(name, rs);
        System.out.println("Service started");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("could not start registry");
    }

}
```

Comment: there's a pretty clear guide [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html#:~:text=A%20Java%20RMI%20registry%20is,a%20client%20needs%20to%20use.). Note that you need to publish a remote interface stub to the registry and you have to start the registry along with your server.

Comment: this guide only works on localhost for me

Comment: `java.rmi.server.hostname` needs to be set *at the server*. Setting it at the client has no effect.

Comment: Which line of code did you get `Connection refused to host: localhost` at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks like your server uses `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);` which implies own registry (same process) which you don't store to local variable, and then you call `Naming.rebind(bind, rs)` which implies use of a local registry (same host, other process) on the default port.

Try changing the lines on server to:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
...
// NOTE registry.rebind not called with name="//42.155.241.914/RemoteBookService"
registry.rebind("RemoteBookService", stub);
```

Hopefully this may get you to the next step, but there are plenty of ways this could have gone wrong so you might need to edit the question with more details.

Comment: thanks, it got me to the next step, maybe you can also help here, the client now connects to the server via the IP and it finds the bound "RemoteBookService" correctly, but as soon as the client tries to execute a remote function then the error appears java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 42.155.241.914; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. The server has released the RMI port 1099.

Comment: Is there a long delay between the connect and first call? You might try seeing if running separate server process `rmiregistry 1099` makes a difference (it needs classpath for client interface though), and connect server to it with `LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port)`.